# React-Leaflet Set fillOpacity of single ellipse on mouseover/mouseout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-question-demo?file=src/components/Map.jsx)

I have a map created with [React-Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) that displays Ellipses created with [Leaflet.ellipse](https://github.com/jdfergason/Leaflet.Ellipse#leafletellipse) and [React-Leaflet Core API](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/core-introduction/).

I'm passing a mouse event handler to the ellipse's [eventHandlers](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-components#evented-behavior) prop. When I hover the mouse over the ellipse, the `fillOpacity` is changed from 0.0 to 0.5, then changed from 0.5 to 0.0 on mouse out.

The problem is that when the event is triggered, the `fillOpacity` for every ellipse changes rather than just the ellipse that is being hovered over. How can I make it so that only the specific ellipse being hovered over has its `fillOpacity` changed?

#### Map Component

---

```js
const Map = () => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  const [fillOpacity, setFillOpacity] = useState(0)

  const onMouseEvent = (event, type) => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'over':
        setFillOpacity(0.5)
        break
      case 'out':
        setFillOpacity(0.0)
        break
      default:
        break
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <MapContainer
        center={[38, -82]}
        zoom={4}
        zoomControl={false}
        style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%", padding: 0 }}
        whenCreated={map => setMap(map)}
      >
        <LayersControl position="topright">
          <LayersControl.BaseLayer checked name="Map">
            <TileLayer
              attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url={maps.base}
            />
          </LayersControl.BaseLayer>
          <LayersControl.Overlay checked name="Ellipses">
            <FeatureGroup>
              <>{CITIES.map((city, index) => {
                return (
                  <Ellipse
                    key={index}
                    center={city.center} 
                    radii={city.radii} 
                    tilt={city.tilt} 
                    pathOptions={{
                      fillOpacity,
                      opacity: 1,
                      weight: 2,
                    }}
                    eventHandlers={{
                      mouseover: (event, type) => onMouseEvent(event, 'over'),
                      mouseout: (event, type) => onMouseEvent(event, 'out'),
                    }}
                  >
                    <Popup>
                      <Typography variant='subtitle1'>{city.city}</Typography>
                    </Popup>
                  </Ellipse>
                )
              })}</>
              </FeatureGroup>
            </LayersControl.Overlay>
        </LayersControl>
      </MapContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

#### Ellipse Component

---

```js
import { createPathComponent } from '@react-leaflet/core'
import L from 'leaflet'
import 'leaflet-ellipse'

const Ellipse = createPathComponent(createEllipse, updateEllipse)

function createEllipse(props, context) {
  const { center, radii, tilt, options } = props
  const instance = new L.Ellipse(center, radii, tilt, options)
  return {
    instance,
    context: { ...context, overlayContainer: instance },
  }
}

function updateEllipse(instance, props, prevProps) {
  if (
    props.center !== prevProps.center ||
    props.radii !== prevProps.radii ||
    props.tilt !== prevProps.tilt ||
    props.options !== prevProps.options
  ) {
    instance.setStyle(props.options)
    instance.setLatLng(props.center)
    instance.setRadius(props.radii)
    instance.setTilt(props.tilt)
  }
}

export default Ellipse
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same state variable for all the elipses.  Here:

```js
{CITIES.map((city, index) => {
  return (
    <Ellipse
      key={index}
      pathOptions={{
        fillOpacity. // <---- problem here
      }}
    >
      ...
    </Ellipse>
  )
})}
```

So *all* ellipses are getting their opacity from the `fillOpacity` state variable.  When you mouse over *any* of them, the state variable changes, and all of them respond.  You'd be better off *not* handling opacity as a state variable.  Just set it to a constant 0, and within the event handler, dig into the `target` of the mouseover, and call `setStyle`:

```js
  const onMouseEvent = (event, type) => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'over':
        event.target.setStyle({ fillOpacity: 0.5 })
        break
      case 'out':
        event.target.setStyle({ fillOpacity: 0.0 })
        break
      default:
        break
    }
  }
```

So now each ellipse manages its own opacity directly through leaflet methods, rather than all inheriting their opacity through a too-broadly-applied react state variable.

### [Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-question-demo-z31hrc)